# Word for being able to contain

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective to qualify something as being able to contain physically other objects? Something like the quality of a container or a storage device. Normally when objects can be classified as storable, containable, holdable, etc, it is refered to their capacity of being stored, contained or held; but what about the capacity of storing, containing and holding other objects?

My point here is to find an adjective that enables me to ask a question regarding something's capability of containing other objects: "Is it _______?" If yes, then it can contain physically other objects (like a container, box, or bag)

Comment: I would use a noun: "Is it *a container*?" Is there any reason you can't use a noun?

Comment: Please see  [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions. We are not a word-puzzle and crossword puzzle site; we're a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts.

Comment: @tchrist, this question was a genuine attempt to find a word to better express a specific concept. At work, we came up with a qualifier that we were unable to name. Hence, I came here for help. I assure you this wasn't a riddle or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an item is ***[fillable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fillable?s=t)***, it is able to have things put inside of it until it reaches a certain capacity.